# Power Series of Invariant Differential

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, formal-power-series

Good evening,

I have some questions about methods of proving using power series of the invariant differential in Silverman's book *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (direct link below). On page 118 (Chap. IV) we are told that the invariant differential $\omega(z) = \frac{dx(z)}{2y(z) + a_1 x(z) +a_3} $ has the power series
$$
\omega(z) = 
(1 + a_1z + ({a_1}^2 + a_2)z^2 + ({a_1}^3 + 2a_1a_2 + 2a_3)z^3 + \cdots) dz \, .
$$
This is not clear to me.

1. How can the denominator $ 2y +a_1x +a_3 $ be successively canceled?

The setting is introduced at the page 115: We analyse the Weierstrass equation around $O$ using the variable transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (z,w)$ so that $z = \frac{-x}{y}$, $w = \frac{-1}{y}$ and show that $w$ can be expressed as a formal series depending on $z$. It's also clear to me how to get the formal series of $x(z)$ and $y(z)$: simply divide the Ws equation $w = f(z,w)$ by $z^2 w$ and solve for $z/w$ .

Second question: Subsequently it is shown that $w(z)$ has coefficients from $ \mathbb{Z}[a_1,..., a_6] $ by using the conclusion (?) that $w(z)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2},a_1,..., a_6][[z]] $ as well as in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3},a_1,..., a_6][[z]]$. This is shown by the fact that $w(z)$ has two representations:
$$
\omega(z)/dz = \frac{dx(z) / dz}{2y + a_1 x +a_3} = \frac{-2z^{-3} + \cdots}{-2z^{-3} + \cdots} \in \mathbb{Z}[{1/2},a_1,\ldots, a_6][[z]] \, ,
$$
as well as
$$
\omega(z)/dz = \frac{dx(z) / dz}{3x^2 + 2a_2 x +a_4 -a_1y} = \frac{-3z^{-4} + \cdots}{-3z^{-4} + \cdots} \in \mathbb{Z}[{1/3},a_1, \ldots, a_6][[z]] \, .
$$
Then the author compares the numerators and denominators. My question is:

2. Why $ \omega(z)/dz $ is in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2},a_1,...,
       a_6][[z]]$ respectively $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2},a_1,..., a_6][[z]]$
   included, and why does this show that any denominator is
   simultaneously a power of $2$ and $3$?

Images of the relevant pages:

[The both problem places...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Oin.png)

WR

KarlRuprecht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do partly with what the expansions of $x$ and $y$ look like, as Laurent series in $z$, the local uniformizing parameter at the point $\Bbb O$ at infinity. the situation is that
$$
x=z^{-2}+z^{-1}\cdot(\text{power series in $z$ with coeffs involving the $a$’s})\,,
$$
so that similarly
$$
dx=\bigl[-2z^{-3}+z^{-2}\cdot(\text{another such power series in $z$})\bigr]dz\,.
$$
Now, $2y+a_1x+a_3$ also has a Laurent-series expansion in $z$ starting out $-2z^3$, again with the other coefficients being polynomials in the $a$’s. Once you form the quotient, you may multiply top and bottom of the fraction by $-z^3/2$, to get something that looks like
$$
\omega=\frac{1+zP(z)}{1+zQ(z)}dz\,,
$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are power series in $z$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z[a_1,\cdots,a_6,\frac12]$. Since the bottom of the fraction has $1$ for its constant term, it has a reciprocal in $\bigl(Z[a_1,\cdots,a_6,\frac12]\bigr)[[z]]$, and there you are.

I hope this has helped.